# Android 9-Patch Background Image Initial PNG Size?

Tags: android, user-interface, nine-patch

I'm looking at making a 9-Patch background image for my application and I'm wondering what size should I make the initial PNG in Photoshop before I convert it to a 9-Patch Image?

Thanks Aaron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Note the combination of screen sizes and densities to consider.

For now, you'll probably want to cover at least three image sizes: 320x480, 480x800, and something for small/LDPI devices.  In the not-too-distant future, you might also want to include an image for XHDPI devices.

The images should be these sizes, *before* adding the 9-patch info.  The 9-patch info will make the actual image sizes larger by 2 pixels in width and height, and that's how it's supposed to work.  So, the 320x480 image will become 322x482.

Comment: Thanks for the reply

So should I create the 3 backgrounds at their respective sizes and place in the folders res/drawable, res/drawable-mdpi, res/drawable-hdpi and then make these 3 images 9-Patch Images? 

I was thinking along the same lines but was really unsure if 9-Patch images can load from folders other than drawable

Thanks Aaron

Comment: Not quite.  Note the following: 1. The drawable-SOMETHINGdpi folders will only work on devices with Android 1.6 and newer. 2. Anything in the plain "drawable" folder could be for just Android 1.5 devices, which are just normal-size/MDPI devices.  So, LDPI graphics would be in drawable-ldpi. 3. You can use XML files in the drawable folders to reference other existing image files.  So, you don't need two copies of MDPI resources.  If what this means isn't quote clear, be sure to thoroughly understand the referenced doc above, and of course, just ask more questions.

Comment: Thanks for the response, as my background image is quite complex I'm finding it hard to make it a 9 Patch image in the respective sizes however I have just created 3 images low, med, high and this seems to work very well on the simulators at the moment. I might go with this approach and just made the buttons 9-patch images in the respective sizes. Also this application will only target 1.6 or higher. I'm still learning the docs but feel I am getting somewhere now. Thanks

Comment: Please review how StackOverflow works at http://stackoverflow.com/faq - especially the "What is reputation?" section.

Comment: If multiple background images are made and put in different drawable folders to fit the screen size there is no point in making it a nine-patch.

Answer (score 3):

Your image can be as small as 5 by 5 to as large as 1280x800...

It really depends what you want to show on that background image. small files are certainly not as exciting as nice fullscreen splash screens designed by a professional :)

If you want your splash screen to fill the screen, you can design your splash screen so it fits the biggest screen out there and put it inside an imageview letting android crop it for smaller screen.

You can also scale the image to fit all resolutions, but this is not as sharp looking.

Comment: I would say this answer fits the question better than the accepted one. Generally you should make the 9-patch as small as possible (as small as the design allows), after all that is the point with it. However, not all backgrounds fits to be 9-patch - and in that case the accepted answer fits as a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that all depends on what you want from the image. Ensure that the image has everything that you need in it before converting it, obviously. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your question.

Comment: I am creating an image in Photoshop for the background of the application which will be full screen behind everything. Kind of like a splash screen. I'm just unsure what resolution I should create it at before making it a 9-Patch Image. Hope that clarifies things.

Comment: There is no point turning a splashscreen into a .9.png. The whole point of the 9-patch is to allow it to scale. Splashscreens in general, don't need to scale. This is especially true if you have a splash screen that contains images.